# How can we detect already uploaded app in app store by installing app in development?

Tags: ios, app-store, development-environment, deep-linking, url-scheme

I'm using adjust.com SDK and their attribution delegate and configured the tracker URL, my app is live on **AppStore**.

What I'm trying to do is, I want to open my app installed on phone built with development/adhoc provisioning profile. So when I open tracker url on phone, it redirect me to Appstore and say "Open" the app or direct open the app due to url scheme configured in app. So I want this in development/testing.

For now after redirection, it says me to download the live version but I want to test tracker url thing before uploading actual app to appstore.

What I'm thinking may be not possible but I was thinking something like is it possible to add something in code that my development app behave like a live **IPA**?

Sorry, if you found a long question but I try to explain it. :) Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Step by step;

1) Remove your application from your device.

2) Reset your advertising identifier via iOS Settings app or remove your device from Adjust using Adjust Testing Console.

3) Click to URL you want to test and go to App Store but don't download your app.

4) Run your app via Xcode.

5-a) Check your device from Adjust testing console and see if it has the tracker ids from your url.

5-b) Alternatively you can check your tracker id on the next launch of your application by printing the Adjust attribution;

```
Adjust.attribution()
```

For more information you can check the official [Adjust Documentation Testing Console section.](http://help.adjust.com/resources/testing-console)

Comment: I tried these steps but did not get response for tracker url created by me. I got one call for organic install but not for my tracker URL.

Comment: Check the documentation page I listed and try to see if you missed any step. And before clicking to tracker URL make sure your device is removed from Adjust via Testing Console. Other than that, you can check your tracker settings. Changing Device fingerprinting for clicks option helped us before.